# Why do the following algorithms for Quadratic Primes perform so differently?

Tags: optimization, cpu, program-optimization

I'm trying to solve for https://projecteuler.net/problem=27, and I have to optimize one part of the implementation from slow() to fast(). Why do they perform so differently? I'm guessing branch predictions, but I don't quite understand how they are different to the optimizer. The code is in javascript.

```javascript
function primes(n) {
    const P = new Array(n).fill(1)
    P[0] = 0
    P[1] = 0
    for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for (let j = 2*i; j <= n; j += i) {
            P[j] = 0
        }
    }
    return P
}
const P = primes(1_000_000)

function slow(a, b) {
    for (let i = 0; ; i++) {
        if (P[i*i+a*i+b] == 0) {
            return i - 1 // the reason why it's slow is probably because of the fork-away of return inside the loop.
        }
    }
}

function fast(a, b) {
    let i
    for (i = 0; P[i*i+a*i+b] == 1; i++) {}
    return i // so this optimization works as long as we only need 1 index value
}

function qp(n, algo = npc) {
    let max = 0
    let maxa, maxb
    for (let a = -n; a <= n; a++) {
        for (let b = -n; b <= n; b++) {
            // here's the trick. CPU can optimize if it can SOMEHOW predict the branch pattern, which probably goes all the way false.
            // if we write npa(), we are nesting another loop-branch within, and then CPU refuses to take a guess on the outer loop.
            const i = algo(a, b)
            if (i > max) {
                max = i
                maxa = a
                maxb = b
            }
        }
    }
    return [maxa, maxb]
}

// pretty much that same:
fast(-61, 971)
slow(-61, 971)

// huge difference:
qp(200, fast)
qp(200, slow)
```

Here are some benchmarks in chromium:

```
     |   n |  time
slow | 100 |   165
     | 200 |  1090
     | 400 | 10176
fast | 100 |    12
     | 200 |    27
     | 400 |    99
```

Comment: My guess is that if this is a compiled language, the compiler somehow managed to remove the entire `for` loop. But honestly it looks weird that there is such a big difference in running time

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I've updated the question to include some benchmarks. For n = 1000, the slow route takes too long for the browser to respond.

Comment: Mentioning the coding language may lessen the concern about index bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally find out I'm just writing bad code that results in too many computations.

The condition in slow() should be `P[i*i+a*i+b] != 1` instead of `P[..] == 0` because there are cases when the index is smaller than 0.

Comment: When the index is negative, you access values outside the array, and reading these values will produce rubbish. Yes, if you compare rubbish != 1 instead of rubbish == 0 that will run faster, because that rubbish is usually neither 1 nor 0. That doesn't change the fact that the result is complete nonsense.

Comment: @gnasher729 It works in javascript, but you are probably right in that I shouldn't rely on these kinds of features of a high-level language.